# Discards qualifiers error

Tags: c++

For my compsci class, I am implementing a Stack template class, but have run into an odd error:

> Stack.h: In member function ‘`const T Stack<T>::top() const` [with T = int]’:
>
> Stack.cpp:10: error: passing ‘`const Stack<int>`’ as ‘`this`’ argument of ‘`void Stack<T>::checkElements()` [with T = int]’ discards qualifiers

`Stack<T>::top()` looks like this:

```
const T top() const {
    checkElements();
    return (const T)(first_->data);
}
```

`Stack<T>::checkElements()` looks like this:

```
void checkElements() {
    if (first_==NULL || size_==0)
        throw range_error("There are no elements in the stack.");
}
```

The stack uses linked nodes for storage, so `first_` is a pointer to the first node.

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your `checkElements()` function is not marked as `const` so you can't call it on `const` qualified objects.

`top()`, however is const qualified so in `top()`, `this` is a pointer to a const `Stack` (even if the `Stack` instance on which `top()` was called happens to be non-`const`), so you can't call `checkElements()` which *always* requires a non-`const` instance.

Answer (score 13):

You cannot call a non-const method from a const method. That would 'discard' the *const* qualifier.

Basically it means that if it allowed you to call the method, then it could change the object, and that would break the promise of not modifying the object that the `const` at the end of the method signature offers.

Answer (score 4):

You're calling a non-const method from a const method.

Answer (score 2):

Because checkElements() isn't declared const.

```
void checkElements() const {
    if (first_==NULL || size_==0)
        throw range_error("There are no elements in the stack.");
}
```

Without that declaration, checkElements cannot be called on a const object.