# Sending a string variable as a parameter to open a file

Tags: c++, function, file, pointers

In main:

```
void HandleAction(const RandomWriter & rw, string choice)
{
   if(choice == "P")
   {
     string fileInput;
     cout << "Change input file: " << endl;
     cin >> fileInput;
     rw.SetFilename(fileInput);
   }
}
```

In a RandomWriter class:

```
void RandomWriter::SetFilename(string filename)
{
 string text = GetFullFile(filename);
 if (text != "")
{
  fullText = text;
  this->filename = filename;
}
```

/

Why am i getting this error when i try to pass fileInput as a parameter to SetFileName?

Thanks in advance guys!

```
||=== error: passing 'const RandomWriter' as 'this' argument of 'void RandomWriter::SetFilename(std::string)' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]|
```

Comment: Read trough the answers here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382834/discards-qualifiers-error

Comment: If you want to check if a `std::string` object is empty or not, there's the [`empty`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/empty) member function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `HandleAction` function you say that the `rw` is a reference to a *constant* `RandomWriter` object. Then you try to call a member function on the `rw` object that tries to *modify* the constant object. That is of course not allowed, you can't modify constant objects.

So the simple solution is to remove the `const` part of the argument specification:

```
void HandleAction(RandomWriter & rw, string choice) { ... }
//                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//         Note: No longer constant
```

---

On a related note, you should probably use references to constant objects for the *strings* though, no need to copy them all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Your `RandomWriter` parameter `rw` is declared `const` in your `HandleAction()` method, and is thus *immutable* and unable to be changed by your call to `SetFilename()`.