# passing '<type>' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++

I have this error on my code:

```
passing 'const Auteur' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
```

Located on `auteur.getNom()`, on that line:

```
cout << titre << ", " << auteur.getNom() << ", en " << langue << endl;
```

The type of `auteur` is `const Auteur&`
Here is the `Oeuvre` class, where the error is located :

```
class Oeuvre {
    private:
    string titre;
    const Auteur& auteur;
    string langue;
    
    public:
    Oeuvre(string titre, const Auteur& auteur, string langue)
    : titre(titre), auteur(auteur), langue(langue) {}
    string getTitre() { return titre; }
    const Auteur& getAuteur() { return auteur; }
    string getLanguage() { return langue; }
    void affiche() {
        
        cout << titre << ", " << auteur.getNom() << ", en " << langue << endl; // the error is here
    }
    ~Oeuvre() {
        cout << "L’oeuvre \"" << titre << ", " << auteur.getNom() << ", en " << langue << "\" n’est plus disponible." << endl;
    }
    Oeuvre(Oeuvre const&) = delete;
};
```

And here is the `Auteur` class, the type of `auteur`:

```
class Auteur {
    private:
    string nom;
    bool prime;
    
    public:
    Auteur(string nom, bool prime = false)
    : nom(nom), prime(prime) {}
    string getNom() { return nom; }
    bool getPrix() { return prime; }
    Auteur(Auteur const&) = delete;
};
```

Comment: It's because of `const`s!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discards qualifiers error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382834/discards-qualifiers-error)

Comment: `string getNom() { return nom; }` should be `string getNom() const { return nom; }` because a getter function normally has no reason to change the object it's being invoked on. In general make everything as restrictive as possible to allow the compiler to trap potential bugs and ease restrictions only when forced to. As an added bonus, if the method promises not to change the object, you can invoke the method on `const` objects.

Comment: @user4581301 ok I didnt knew that we can add a const to a method ! Thank you very much

Comment: You can think of the trailing `const` as a `const` specifier on the hidden `this` parameter. Technically `this` isn't a parameter, but it's usually implemented as one.

Comment: @user4581301 so in general cases, when I want to implement a simple getter method, I should put a const, unless i want to modify the object ?

Comment: @user4581301 what is `this` ? I don't really get it

Comment: When you `return nom;`, the compiler sees it as `return this->nom;`. `this` is a pointer to the object the method is being invoked on. [Here's a great documentation page on `this`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/this), but it's mostly written in Martian so you'll probably have to follow a lot of the embedded links to find out what they're talking about. Your question is about *cv-qualification*, the *c* part of it at any rate. [This link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/this-pointer?view=msvc-170) is a lot easier to read, but not quite as accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Why you get this error: Imagine auteur.h just had this

```
class Auteur {
    private:
    string nom;
    bool prime;
    
    public:
    Auteur(string nom, bool prime = false)
    : nom(nom), prime(prime){}
    string getNom();
    bool getPrix();
    Auteur(Auteur const&) = delete;
};
```

and the implementations were in a different file (auteur.cpp). This is a very common thing to do

The compiler doesnt know if getnom will change the Autuer object it is called on. getnom could say:

```
   string Autuer::getnom(){
       string temp = name;
       name = "";
       return name;
   }
```

it doesnt know. Then you try to do this

```
   const Auteur& auteur;
   autuer.getnom();
```

this cant work because you have said that autuer is const. You know getnom is read only but the compiler doesnt (I know it could do by looking at the .h file in this case , but it doesnt)

So you have to promise the compiler that getnom doesnt change the object its called on

```
string getNom() const;
```